# Two .NET objects that are equal don't say they are

Tags: c#, equals, equality

I have the following code:

```
object val1 = 1;
object val2 = 1;

bool result1 = (val1 == val2);//Equals false
bool result2 = val1.Equals(val2); //Equals true
```

What's up with that? Is the only way to fix this to go with .Equals() method?

Comment: The say they are equal but two differrent instances

Comment: Dude, == and .Equals do 2 different things. == operator checks to see if val1 and val2 occupy the same memory space (reference). .Equals checks for content equality.

Comment: You can also use the `object.Equals(object,object)` static method, which first attempts to compare the objects using the `==` operator and then tries the `object.Equals(object)` method if both parameters are not null.  The reason I suggest it is so that you don't have to check for null before calling `object.Equals(object,object)`, whereas you do if you call `object.Equals(object)`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The operator `==` is static, not virtual, so the behaviour is determined by the static type and not the runtime type. The *default* implementation for `==` on objects of reference type is to compare the references (although types can implement a different behaviour, for example `string`). You have two different objects and they don't have the same reference so `==` returns false.

The solution, as you point out, is to use Equals. Equals is a virtual method. Since `value1` has runtime type `Int32` you end up calling [Int32.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3wwa8z.aspx). From .NET Reflector you can see that the implementation of this is as follows:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return ((obj is int) && (this == ((int) obj)));
}
```

In other words, it checks if the argument is of type `int`, and if so casts it and uses the `==` that is defined for `int`. This compares the *values* of the integers.

> Is the only way to fix this to go with .Equals() method?

An alternative is to cast your objects to `int` and then use `==`, just as the implementation of `Int32.Equals` does.

Comment: This seems to be the only correct answer (or, at least, I'm pretty sure you can use == on string and have it work as expected).

Comment: Okay, I don't understand why *Equals* works here. According to the docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx "The default implementation of *Equals* supports reference equality for reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference equality means the object references that are compared refer to the same *object*. "

Comment: @John C: Good question. Does my updated answer make it clearer?

Comment: yes, thanks, that makes sense now. And I presume for your own user-defined classes, you're expected to supply your own definition of Equals.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. `==` checks for reference equality. Use `Equals` where you want to compare content.

You might be wondering why this is so with objects. When you set an integer (value type) to an object variable, an operation called boxing happens. This operation wraps the value type into an object and puts it on the heap and returns a reference. This happens twice and references becomes different (although the values are the same).

Answer (score 2):

`==` checks whether the two objects are *identical*. They are not. They represent the same number, but are stored at different locations in memory.

It’s like comparing two apples. Both are *apples* and look the same, but they are different objects.

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you cast them to objects they are "converted" to references to int values. And the two references are not equal.
But equals compares the referenced values instead of the references.

Answer (score 0):

Two objects are equal if they point to the same space in memory.

```
val1 == val1; //Equals true
```

As pointed by tc you can make an operator overload.

```
public static bool operator ==(Object a, Object b)
```

This way the behavior of the operator `==` will be the one defined by this method.

You should also overload the operator `!=` when you overload `==`.

Comment: Unless there's an operator overload.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using `object` but a custom class, you can override the == and != operators, and should probably implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface

```
public static bool operator ==(MyType left, MyType right)
{
    //code here, don't forget about NULLS when writing comparison code!!!
}

public static bool operator !=(MyType left, MyType right)
{
    return !(left == right);
}

public bool Equals(MyType x, MyType y)
{
    return (x == y);
}

public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
{
    return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) for your code boxes the two integers and compares the two objects that result from the boxing (==). This comparison is by reference.

```
  .locals init ([0] object val1,
           [1] object val2,
           [2] bool result1,
           [3] bool result2)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0002:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0009:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_000e:  stloc.1
  IL_000f:  ldloc.0
  IL_0010:  ldloc.1
  IL_0011:  ceq
  IL_0013:  stloc.2
  IL_0014:  ldloc.0
  IL_0015:  ldloc.1
  IL_0016:  callvirt   instance bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object)
  IL_001b:  stloc.3
```

For the .Equals it calls Object.Equals, which calls Int32.Equals (virtual method call on Object):

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return ((obj is int) && (this == ((int) obj)));
}
```

This casts to int and compares the values as integers, a value type comparison.