# How to determine if two generic type values are equal?

Tags: c#, generics, comparison

**Update***
I am so sorry... my sample code contained an error which resulted in a lot of answers I didn't understand.
In stead of

```
Console.WriteLine("3. this.Equals   " + (go1.Equals(go2)));
```

I meant to write

```
Console.WriteLine("3. this.Equals   " + (go1.Equals(sb2)));
```

---

I'm trying to figure out how I can successfully determine if two generic type values are equal to each other. Based on Mark Byers' answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470145/two-net-objects-that-are-equal-dont-say-they-are) I would think I can just use `value.Equals()` where value is a generic type.
My actual problem is in a LinkedList implementation, but the problem can be shown with this simpler example.

```
class GenericOjbect<T> {
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public GenericOjbect(T value) {
        Value = value;
    }
    public bool Equals(T value) {
        return (Value.Equals(value));
    }
}
```

Now I define an instance of `GenericObject<StringBuilder>` containing `new StringBuilder("StackOverflow")`. I would expect to get `true` if I call `Equals(new StringBuilder("StackOverflow")` on this GenericObject instance, but I get `false`.

A sample program showing this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var sb1 = new StringBuilder("StackOverflow");
        var sb2 = new StringBuilder("StackOverflow");

        Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder compare");
        Console.WriteLine("1. ==            " + (sb1 == sb2));
        Console.WriteLine("2. Object.Equals " + (Object.Equals(sb1, sb2)));
        Console.WriteLine("3. this.Equals   " + (sb1.Equals(sb2)));

        var go1 = new GenericOjbect<StringBuilder>(sb1);
        var go2 = new GenericOjbect<StringBuilder>(sb2);

        Console.WriteLine("\nGenericObject compare");
        Console.WriteLine("1. ==            " + (go1 == go2));
        Console.WriteLine("2. Object.Equals " + (Object.Equals(go1, sb2)));
        Console.WriteLine("3. this.Equals   " + (go1.Equals(sb2)));
        Console.WriteLine("4. Value.Equals  " + (go1.Value.Equals(sb2.Value)));
    }
}
```

For the three methods of comparing two StringBuilder objects, only the StringBuilder.Equals instance method (the third line) returns `true`. This is what I expected. But when comparing the GenericObject objects, its Equals() method (the third line) returns `false`. Interestingly enough, the fourth compare method *does* return `true`. I'd think the third and fourth comparison are actually doing the same thing.

I would have expected `true`. Because in the Equals() method of the GenericObject class, both `value` and `Value` are of type `T` which in this case is a `StringBuilder`. Based on Mark Byers' answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470145/two-net-objects-that-are-equal-dont-say-they-are), I would've expected the `Value.Equals()` method to be using the StringBuilder's Equals() method. And as I've shown, the StringBuilder's Equal() method does return `true`.

I've even tried

```
public bool Equals(T value) {
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Value, value);
}
```

but that also returns false.

So, two questions here:

1. Why doesn't the code return `true`?
2. How could I implement the `Equals` method so it *does* return `true`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639443/how-to-determine-if-two-generic-type-values-are-equal/4639504#4639504), the problem is with `StringBuilder` `Equals(object)` implementation that is different to the one in `Equals(StringBuilder)`.

Then, you can ignore the problem because your code will work with any other coherently-implemented classes, or you can use dynamic to fix the problem (again as suggested by Mark Gravell).

But, given that you are not using C# 4 (so no dynamic), you can try in this way:

```
public bool Equals(T value)
{
   // uses Reflection to check if a Type-specific `Equals` exists...
   var specificEquals = typeof(T).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(T) });
   if (specificEquals != null &&
       specificEquals.ReturnType == typeof(bool))
   {
       return (bool)specificEquals.Invoke(this.Value, new object[]{value});
   }
   return this.Value.Equals(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does do the trick. If I understand correctly, for an other type my original Equals method should work. I've tried using new Exception("StackOverflow"), but again my original code doesn't return `true`. Can you suggest another reference type class in the .NET Framework which I can simply check my `Equals` implementation?

Comment: BTW, why should a class have to implement an override on Equals(Object)? Should a class have to define both `Equals(type of class itself)` as well as `Equals(Object)` in order to be considered "coherently-implemented"?

Comment: If your class is cast to an object or used in a generic method/class (like your case), the default `Equals(object)` is called. So if you implement your custom `Equals(type of class itself)` why you shouldn't override the default-one too? Also, it is one line of code: `return this.Equals(obj as TypeOftheClass);`. This is more coherent IMO.

Comment: I can't be aware of .NET classes Equals implementation until I try it, but anyway you can easily write your own classes implementing the 2 Equals methods and test them :)

Comment: I wonder how the .NET System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList performs it Find() method. Because that version **is** able to Find(sb2) after adding (sb1).

Comment: @comecme: are you sure ? It doesn't work for me (I've tried it). And BTW `LinkedList.Find()` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` (I've checked that using red gate's reflector to disassemble the code)

Comment: @digEmAll: I though I was sure. But when I reviewed my test case again, I noticed I made an error there too. I must start triple checking my code!

Answer (score 6):

Your code looks fine. The problem here is that StringBuilder has a confusing set of Equals that are contradictory. In particular, Equals(StringBuilder) disagrees with Equals(object), even when the object **is** a StringBuilder.

All that `EqualityComparer<T>` **needs** is a sane Equals(object) implementation. The interface (`IEquatable<T>`) is optional. Unfortunately StringBuilder doesn't have this (at least, by comparison to Equals(StringBuilder), which your third test is using).

But in general, the advice is: use `EqualityComparer<T>`; this supports:

- nullable-of-T with standard "lifted" rules
- IEquatable-of-T
- object.Equals

Comment: +1: didn't know about StringBuilder Equals set. This, plus the fact he's implementing `Equals(T v)` instead of `Equals(GenericObject<T> v)` is the problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that the `return (value.Equals(Value))` in my Equals method calls the StringBuilder's Equals(object) method? If so, why? Is it because a generic type like T is actually considered an object?

Comment: @digEmAll: I don't want to compare to another `GenericObject<T>`, but to another `T`. If I want to compare to `GenericObject<T>` instances, wouldn't I be just comparing if the both point to the same object? In fact, `Equals(GenericObject<T> genericObject)` doesn't even compile.

Comment: @comecme exactly; generics use the same methods for **all** the T - so unless you have a generic type constraint, it will only spot methods on object. Note that `dynamic` may be useful; it uses the most appropriate method available **at runtime** for each individual T.

Comment: It is perhaps unfortunate that StringBuilder is the example here ; it adds confusion :)

Comment: @digEmAll: On the line `public bool Equals(GenericObject<T> genericObject)` I get an error "The type or namespace name 'GenericObject' could not be found".

Comment: @comecme: you have a 3rd problem: you spelled wrong your class name: `GenericOjbect` instead of `GenericObject` ;)

Comment: @digEmAll. That's my second stupid mistake. Now the code does compile. But as my updated question shows, I didn't even want to compare to another `GenericObject<T>`, just a `T`.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I can't use `dynamic` as I'm using .NET 3.5 here (and VS2008)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I used StringBuilder because I was looking for a simple .NET object to use for testing my LinkedList implementation. At first I tried a `DateTime`, but that's a structure in stead of a class. The next type that came to mind was a StringBuilder.

Comment: @comecme: look at my answer for a working .NET 3.5 solution (truly truly inpired to this answer, that should be accepted IMO)

Comment: @comecme `string` would have been my choice of a reference-type to use :)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I already used string, but assumed it only works because C# treats a `string` as though it is a value type. That's exactly why I was trying to use another .NET type, one that actually *is* a reference type.

Comment: @comecme: C# treats strings like other classes. String it's just an immutable class that overrides `Equals`, `CompareTo`, `==`, `!=` etc.

Comment: @comecme - to echo that; string **is** a reference-type

Answer (score 3):

Line 3 with the generic object is not calling your custom written method.  Instead, it is calling the base `Object.Equals(object)`.  To call your custom method, you need to pass in a `T` not a `GenericObject<T>`.  Something like: `go1.Equals(go2.Value)`

Comment: You are right about line 3 calling `Object.Equals(object)`. However, using `go1.Equals(go2.Value)` doesn't make any difference. Also, what I want to write here is an Equals method on GenericObject that is able to compare two GenericObject instances.

Comment: @comecme: stringbuilder has contradictory equals method. Read Marc Gravell's answer ;)

Comment: If I rename my `Equals` method to `MyEquals` it doesn't work. The 3rd line now does call my MyEquals method. But its `return (value.Equals(Value)` still returns `false`.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I didn't mean to use `go1.Equals(go2)` but `go1.Equals(sb2)`. So now I **do** pass in a `T`, and the `Equals` gets called. However, it still returns `false`. I've updated my Question.

Answer (score 2):

As Eric Lippert says in answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678703/generic-overload-resolution) - Overload resolution is performed at compile time.

If you take a look at `StringBuilder`'s implementation you will notice it overloads `Equals` and does not override it.  This is basically the root of the problem as to why `StringBuilder.Equals` does not work as you expected in your example.

Take the following 2 classes as example.  `Overloader` is analogous to `StringBuilder` in the example as it overloads `Equals`.  `Overrider` is very similar except it it overrides `Equals` instead.

```
public class Overloader
{
  public string Str {get;private set;}
  public Overloader (string str) {Str = str;}

  public bool Equals( Overloader str )
  {
    return this.Str.Equals( str );
  }
}

public class Overrider
{
  public string Str {get;private set;}
  public Overrider (string str) {Str = str;}

  public override bool Equals( object obj )
  {
    if ( obj is Overrider )
    {
      return this.Str.Equals( (obj as Overrider).Str );
    }
    return base.Equals( obj );
  }
}
```

I have slightly modified your `GenericObject<T>` class in my example:

```
class GenericOjbect<T>
{
  public T Value {get;private set;}
  public GenericOjbect( T val ) {Value = val;}

  public bool Equals( T val )
  {
    return Value.Equals( val );
  }

  public override bool Equals( object obj )
  {
    if ( obj is T )
    {
      return this.Equals( ( T )obj );
    }
    if (obj != null && obj is GenericOjbect<T> )
    {
      return this.Equals( ( obj as GenericOjbect<T> ).Value );
    }
    return base.Equals( obj );
  }
}
```

In this sample program you will see that `Overloader` (or `Stringbuilder` for that matter) will return false.  However, `Overrider` returns true.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    var goOverloader1 = new GenericOjbect<Overloader>( new Overloader( "StackOverflow" ) );
    var goOverloader2 = new GenericOjbect<Overloader>( new Overloader( "StackOverflow" ) );

    var goOverrider1 = new GenericOjbect<Overrider>( new Overrider( "StackOverflow" ) );
    var goOverrider2 = new GenericOjbect<Overrider>( new Overrider( "StackOverflow" ) );

    Console.WriteLine( "Overrider  : {0}", goOverloader1.Equals( goOverloader2 ) ); //False
    Console.WriteLine( "Overloader : {0}", goOverrider1.Equals( goOverrider2 ) ); //True
  }
}
```

Referencing Eric Lippert again - Overload resolution is performed at compile time.  Meaning that the compiler basically looks at your `GenericObject<T>.Equals( T val )` like this:

```
public bool Equals( T val )
{
  return Value.Equals( (Object) val );
}
```

To anwser your question **How to determine if two generic type values are equal?**.  There's two things you possibly could do.

1. If you *own* all the objects that will be wrapped in `GenericObject<T>` ensure they all *at least* override `Equals`.
2. You could perform some reflection magic in your `GenericObject<T>.Equals(T val)` to manually perform late binding.

Comment: It's too bad I can only mark one answer as the accepted answer. You do explain the problem very well, but digEmAl gave me a code sample that actually *will* return true on the StringBuilders. If I have to choose, and I do have to do that, I'm leaning more towards digEmAl's anwser.

Comment: @comecme - No worries.  It took me a while to understand what was going on and I didn't see that digEmAll had given you working code.

Answer (score 1):

You can either implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), or implement a comparer class that implements [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).

Make sure that `value` you check for equality is immutable and is set only at initialization of the class.

Another consideration would be to implement [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx), when you implement this one, you don't have to worry about the hash-code, and thus, can be implemented for mutable types/fields as well.

Once you'll **[properly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IEquatable.aspx)** implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) in your class, your questions will be solved.

Update:
Calling `return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Value, value);` would basically return same result since there is no `IEqualityComparer<T>` implemented...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The IEquatable<T> interface only contains an Equals method. The problem I'm having is **how** to determine the equality. So how would implementing IEquatable<T> help me? I would still implement `IEquatable<T>.Equals` as `return (value.Equals(Value));` and get the same (incorrect) result.

Comment: Why does  `value` have to be immutable?

Comment: The problem will be if you work with dictionaries, hashtables etc. that use GetHashCode, when you implement IEquatable<T>, you should also override GetHashCode, and if GetHashCode is based on a mutable field it will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: I emphasized the word [properly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IEquatable.aspx), goto link to read more.

Comment: Though this explanation is really good, it has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the output of typeof() first, so you make sure you are comparing the same type of objects, then write an Equals method on X class which takes another instance of X class, and compare all properties... once you find something different, return false, else keep going till you return true.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [Gideon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639443/how-to-determine-if-two-generic-type-values-are-equal/4639489#4639489) (please upvote his, not mine): the method you defined has signature

```
bool GenericOjbect<T>::Equals( T )
```

While your code is calling

```
bool GenericOjbect<T>::Equals( GenericOjbect<T> )
```

which is inherited (not overridden) from `Object`.

Comment: Finally I saw what you were talking about. My test program class used `go1.Equals(go2)` where I meant to say `go1.Equals(sb2)`. So I **do** want to have a `Equals(T value)`. My class showed my intention, my test program caused a lot of confusion. I've updated my question.